# Передача картинки массивом байт по Websocket

Tags: java, android, kotlin, websocket

**Возможно ли декодировать картинку с android устройство и передать по websocket`у?**
Есть ли пример кода или статья которую можно прочитать.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить ознакомится с вариантом кода который я использую у себя в проекте. Допускаю что картинку вы будете брать из файловой системы и поэтому обработка будет происходить в методе `onActivityResult`:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when {
            requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                if (data != null) {
                    val fileUri = data.data!!
                    var name = ""
                    var size: Long? = null

                    fileUri.let { returnUri ->
                        contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
                    }?.use { cursor ->
                        val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                        cursor.moveToFirst()
                        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                        size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                    }


                    val content = data.data?.let { uri -> contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { it!!.readBytes() } }
                    val fileContent = String(content!!, Charsets.ISO_8859_1)

                    sendFilePart(0, fileContent, name, size!!)
                  
                }
            }

            requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                if (data != null) {
                     ....
                }

            }


            else -> {
            }
        }

    }
```

в коде выше вы получаете файл и дальше вытаскиваете из него байты `content` , имя `name`  и размер `size`. Дальше лично у меня идет отправка файла в том формате который принимает сокет, а именно в текстовом:

```
 ws.send(ChatRequestMessages.sendFilePart(fileContent, fileName, fileSize))
```

переменная `fileContent` идет в стринг поэтому можете делать дальше что вам нужно по вашему заданию. Может поможет такой способ, если что-то будет непонятно - спрашивайте :)

Answer (score 0):

С проблемой разобрался! Но на заметку ***фотографии отправляются в уменьшеном размере***

onActivityResult

```
val bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
ivStudentPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
val byteArrayOutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutput)
photoArray = byteArrayOutput.toByteArray()
```

Button

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO);
```